# How to use configuration profile to force DNS-over-HTTPS for every network except the specified SSIDs?

Tags: ios, mdm, configuration-profiles

I want to be able to force DoH on all networks (Wifi, cellular data, etc) except my home and work wifi network SSIDs.

I used iMazing Profile Editor to craft this profile, but when I try to import it on to my iPhone 12 mini (iOS 16.1) it displays an error saying "The field 'OnDemandRules' is not valid." I've read through Apple's Configuration Payload documentation and can't see anything wrong, so I'm guessing there's just something I don't understand.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>PayloadContent</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>DNSSettings</key>
            <dict>
                <key>DNSProtocol</key>
                <string>HTTPS</string>
                <key>ServerAddresses</key>
                <array>
                    <string>185.228.168.168</string>
                    <string>185.228.169.168</string>
                    <string>2a0d:2a00:0001:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000</string>
                    <string>2a0d:2a00:0002:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000</string>
                </array>
                <key>ServerURL</key>
                <string>https://doh.cleanbrowsing.org/doh/family-filter/</string>
            </dict>
            <key>OnDemandRules</key>
            <dict>
                <key>Action</key>
                <string>Disconnect</string>
                <key>SSIDMatch</key>
                <array>
                    <string>eduroam</string>
                    <string>AEROHIVE</string>
                </array>
            </dict>
            <key>PayloadDisplayName</key>
            <string>DNS Settings #1</string>
            <key>PayloadIdentifier</key>
            <string>com.apple.dnsSettings.managed.50552866-1CD2-48AD-8117-EF6EF0CC0920</string>
            <key>PayloadType</key>
            <string>com.apple.dnsSettings.managed</string>
            <key>PayloadUUID</key>
            <string>12B12860-090C-4FE4-B1C4-F1BDC4741DF3</string>
            <key>PayloadVersion</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>PayloadDisplayName</key>
    <string>CleanBrowsing DoH</string>
    <key>PayloadIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.charlesrc019.CleanBrowsingDoH</string>
    <key>PayloadOrganization</key>
    <string>charlesrc019</string>
    <key>PayloadType</key>
    <string>Configuration</string>
    <key>PayloadUUID</key>
    <string>FF112954-D8A9-4C71-8868-9CEC20238482</string>
    <key>PayloadVersion</key>
    <integer>1</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Note: If I edit the profile and take the 'OnDemandRules' section out, it does work, but that doesn't work for what I'm trying to do. I need it to be able to switch between forcing DoH and not depending on what wifi network it is connected to. Also, I am unable to find an documentation saying that On Demand Rules only work for VPN settings not DNS. iMazing Profile Editor included On Demand Rules in their DNS settings, so I'm inclined to believe that it should work.